# How to schedule a task in Python each week day every n seconds

Tags: python, schedule

I want my Python code to execute a function every week day (**Monday to Friday**) and not on weekends (**Saturday and Sunday**)

Is there an easy way to achieve this using the schedule library?

So far I have manage to execute the function every day, every 10 seconds. But this will also execute it on Saturdays and Sundays

```
def helloWorld():
    print("Hello World!!!")


schedule.every(10).days.seconds.do(helloWorld)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Did you try a cron job? Max frequency would be 1 minute though.

Comment: I haven't tried a cron job, I'll look into that instead. 1 minute is totally fine

Comment: You could also consider `systemctl systemd` [calendar events](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events)

Answer (score 1):

You can do an if statement that checks the weekday (Monday is 0):

```
if datetime.datetime.now().weekday() < 5:
    do_something()
```

I agree with Ankit that a cron job might be more stable.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is to replace your

.days with .monday through .friday

That way you could shedule 5 Task that run on Monday through Friday and all 5 jobs would do nothing on all other days.

for reference for some examples with monday instead of days
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I've already tired that, but unfortunately it causes an error asking to change 'monday' to 'mondays'. When I change it to 'mondays' it causes and AttributeError